# UILocalNotification when I take off application

Tags: ios, objective-c, uilocalnotification

I have created a UILocalNotification with

```
localNotification.fireDate = [CurrentDate dateByAddingTimeInterval:+60
```

So, After 60s, it will notification for me.

### And my AppDelegate, I have call method.

```
(void)application:(UIApplication *)application didReceiveLocalNotification:(UILocalNotification *)notification
{

    // Request to reload table view data
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:@"reloadData" object:self];

    NSLog(@"OK...");

    // Set icon badge number to zero
    application.applicationIconBadgeNumber = 0;
}
```

When I click on notification, it is called `didReceiveLocalNotification` method. It is OK.

But when I click in App's Icon in screen, it is not called `didReceiveLocalNotification` method.

I have research and followed this code in `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions`

```
// Handle launching from a notification
    UILocalNotification *notification = [launchOptions objectForKey:UIApplicationLaunchOptionsLocalNotificationKey];

    // If not nil, the application was based on an incoming notifiation
    if (notification){
        NSLog(@"test...");
    }
```

But, it is not working.

It is get notification = nil.

So, it is not NSLog(@"test...");

Please help me!

Answer (score 0):

when app icon is clicked its not local notification click, where as your code in `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions` works in the case when app is not running in background and user or you click on local notification. Whereas whenever app icon is clicked not always `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions`is called, it is called only when app starts i.e not present in background but, `applicationDidBecomeActive` is called whenever app starts from anywhere in any mode. UIApplicationDelegate [https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIApplicationDelegate_Protocol]